# Google App Engine kills static backend when memory hits 100MB, regardless of instance class

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memory

I'm using Python with Google App Engine. When the memory usage gets to 100MB, App Engine stops my backend process and moves it to a different machine. The log file says "Process moved to a different machine."

I would expect this with instance class B1, but it still does it with instance class B2 or even B4_1G. I get billed for the extra memory, but the app engine doesn't appear to give it to me.  I have a static module with this configuration


`application: happycyborg1
module: static-backend
version: 2
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
instance_class: B2
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1 
libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
- name: numpy
  version: "1.6.1"
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: live.APP`

The memory usage on the dashboard looks like this
[image: Process killed when reaching 100MB of memory.]
Each drop corresponds to where the process was moved to a different machine. Ignore that rise at the end. I am trying using multiple instances to get more memory, but I would prefer a single instance with bigger memory.

Also, I don't know why the memory continues to rise. When I log the memory over time, it just bumps up randomly not associated with any area of the code. Because of the data my application uses, I can't easily run it in the local environment to use testing tools. But when I run it completely outside of app engine, the core code of the app does not increase memory consumption over time.

Comment: Are you doing a lot of RPC calls (such as NDB or URLFetch)?

Comment: Yes. I'm going a lot of NDB and also making calls to Twitter. How can that cause this behavior? I'm checking exceptions on the calls to Twitter. Are there a set of gotchas with NDB? And if so, why do they get triggered at 100 MB? Maybe my entity groups are too large or something?

Comment: There an issue with NDB filling up the memory. Its not the reason for your instance restarting at 100 mb but it might be the reason your filling up that much. Can you send the work to a Mapreduce?

Comment: Just adding a link with more info, supplementing the two comments above:  https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9610

Comment: Yeah, that definitely looks relevant. Very depressing. I'll look into sending it to Mapreduce as well. I'll post more after I investigate. Thanks!

Comment: If you don't mind a little hack, you can convert from NDB to DB objects before performing operations on retrieved entities.  Curtis created a patch with unit tests that show how to do this:  https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/attachmentText?id=9610&aid=96100017000&name=fix.py&token=ABZ6GAc8TvJ5H8yAriq_ojpP_SU_ha7oMg%3A1415723149823.  I haven't used the hack but know of dozens of similarly frustrated engineers that have!